# Using a toggle switch as a momentary switch

Tags: analog, switches, toggle-switch, analog-switch

On my boat I have a 12 V to 220 V voltage converter which is tucked away behind a cabinet. This converter uses a remote control to turn it on or off. Now this remote control is connected with an RJ10 connector to the converter and has a little circuit board built into it so when the momentary switch on the remote is pushed, a light turns on and the converter turns on, when pushed again the light and the converter turns off again.

I would like to use the two wires going to the momentary push switch to connect up my own toggle button on my dashboard and be able to use the toggle switch to do the same task as the momentary switch does. (BTW, the remote controller works on 12 V!) How can I accomplish this?

Remote: https://nedis.com/en-us/product/cables-and-adapters/energy/power-inverters/550688404/power-inverter-remote-control-500-m-rj10-white

Comment: Which toggle switch are you using?

Comment: Why use a toggle switch, when there are momentary contact switches you could wire in parallel?

Comment: Okke, I'm not questioning your decision. I will assume that you have good reason to want to use a toggle switch on your dashboard. But you do need to explain more about what the reason is, so that we can interpret the situation better, or else be very detailed about how you plan to use the toggle switch, in practice. What's obvious to you may not be obvious to others who lack your situational awareness and experience. Also, you may need to address some of the comments here. Just FYI.

Answer (score 2):

the following  toggle momentary switch emulator might work for you.

it only works for DC loads

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYObme.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Your options are going to be:

Get a proper momentary switch that fits the desired install.

If your switch is single-throw (spst or dpst), your going to have to double toggle it every time to replicate the the momentary action.

Or, if you are lucky and your switch is double throw (spdt or dpdt), you may be able to exploit the "make-before-break" characteristic of typical toggle switches: just tie the two switched contacts together and hook one of your inverter control leads to this junction and the other control lead to the switch common (usually the middle terminal). In theory, either toggle will provide a momentary pulse for the invertor. In practice, this may not work due to the invertor input circuitry discriminating this transient event: debouncing and noise immunity - the pulse may not be long enough to render invertor power control.